# RequireConfirmedEmail for normal logins but not external logins (identity core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

setting `RequireConfirmedEmail` at identity options returns `SignInResult.NotAllowed` on the result of signing the user in, it's tested at `CanSignInAsync`

```
if (Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail && !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
```

but this apply to external logins too, which is a behaviour we would like to only have on normal logins

we already know that we can extend the `SignInManager<TUser>` but we thought maybe someone have a simpler more elegant solution, anyone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to set `EmailConfirmed = true` when you create the *external user*, like in the default template method `ExternalLoginConfirmation`:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, 
                                 Email = model.Email, 
                                 EmailConfirmed = true };
```

Comment: i accepted it for the lack of a better answer, but it's just not right (at least for our application to mark an unconfirmed user as confirmed) but we will make it work, thanks tho

Comment: Shouldn't the external login be considered to be confirmed (by the external provider)?

Comment: yes, but in theory, as in people may not have access to this email anymore, and it only takes one stupid move to lock oneself out of their account (like 2FA, or removing the external login from the account) but yes in theory (even that i remember that you can create a facebook account and sign in before confirmation, but not sure if that is still possible and if that will allow external login)